# Как подключить Export в Delphi

Tags: delphi, teechart

По нажатию на кнопку, должно появиться окошко[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

оно находится в TChart во вкладке General.

PrintPreview я нашел как

```
uses TeePrevi;

...

begin

ChartPreview(Self,Chart1);

end;
```

а как export добавить?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример, наглядно демонстрирующий проблему.

Comment: procedure TForm1.Button7Click(Sender: TObject);

begin

ChartPreview(Self,Chart1);
end;
//Как подключить export
procedure TForm1.Button8Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
 //ChartExport(Self,Chart1);  
end; В первой процедуре я подключил Принт привью, во второй я пытался по аналогии подключить экспорт. Что добавить в uses и в тело процедуры

Comment: Отредактируйте вопрос

Answer (score 2):

Возможно, вам нужно добавить:

```
uses teExport;

  TeeExport(Self,Chart1);
```

Comment: в uses  я добавил Teexport, а между begin и end.  with TTeeExportForm.Create(Self) do
  try
    ExportPanel:=Chart1;
    ShowModal();
  finally
    Free();
end; и все вышло